# store hidden field value and show them on next page in mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, hidden-field

In JavaScript hidden field value is stored.

But when clicked on next page hidden field is null it doesn't have values  from previous page.

Why is it not loading previous values in next page?

How to load previous value in hidden field??

```js
function AddRemoveCustomer(id) {
  //$(".checkBoxClass").click(function (e) {
  alert('in main function');
  alert(id);

  var CustomerIDArray = [];
  var hidCID = document.getElementById("hfCustomerID");
  if (hidCID != null && hidCID != 'undefined') {
    var CustID = hidCID.value;
    CustomerIDArray = CustID.split("|");
    var currentCheckboxValue = id;
    var index = CustomerIDArray.indexOf(currentCheckboxValue);
    alert('index value:' + index);
    debugger;
    if (index == 0) {
      alert('if');
      CustomerIDArray.push(currentCheckboxValue);
      alert('pushed value:' + CustomerIDArray);
    } else {
      alert('else');
      var a = CustomerIDArray.splice(index, 1);
      alert("a" + a);

    }
    hidCID.value = CustomerIDArray.join("|");
    alert('Final' + hidCID.value);

  } else {
    alert('undefined');
  }
  //});
}
```

```html
<table id="tblEmailScheduler" class="table-bordered col-offset-12">
  <thead>
    <tr class="label-primary">
      <th style="padding:5px 15px;">
        First Name
      </th>
      <th style="padding:5px 15px;">
        Last Name
      </th>
      <th style="padding:5px 15px;">
        Email ID
      </th>
      <th style="padding:5px 15px;">
        Customer Type
      </th>
      <th style="padding:5px 15px;">
        Customer Designation @Html.DropDownList("CustomerDesignation", new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectAllCustomerDesignationDDL, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "CustomerDesignationDDL" , name = "CustomerDesignationDDL" })
      </th>
      <th style="padding:5px 15px;">
        Select All
        <div class="checkbox control-group">
          <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbSelectAll" /></label>
        </div>
      </th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">
        EmailTemplate : @Html.DropDownList("EmailSubject", new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectAllEmailTemplateDDL, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "SelectAllEmailTemplateDDL" })
      </th>
      <th colspan="2">
        Set Date And Time:
        <input type="text" class="from-date-picker" readonly="readonly" />
      </th>
      <th colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Schedule" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default" />
      </th>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  @foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td id="tblFirstName">
      @item.FirstName
    </td>
    <td id="tblLastName">
      @item.LastName
    </td>
    <td id="tblEmailID">
      @item.EmailID
    </td>
    <td id="tblCustomerType">
      @item.CustomerType
    </td>
    <td id="tblCustomerDesignation">
      @item.CustomerDesignation
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="checkbox control-group">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="@item.CustomerID" value="@item.CustomerID" 
        onclick="AddRemoveCustomer(@item.CustomerID)" class="checkBoxClass"/>
        @*@Html.CheckBox("Select", new { id = "cbCustomer", item.CustomerID})*@</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  }
</table>
<input type="hidden" id="hfCustomerID" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In looking at your code, I noticed an issue that may be causing you the problem you indicate:

```
var index = CustomerIDArray.indexOf(currentCheckboxValue);
```

you then use index to decide if the Id is in the array, by doing this:

```
if (index == 0) {
```

it should be

`if (index == -1) {`

as -1 indicated not found.  With it as it is currently, it would hit this line:

```
var a = CustomerIDArray.splice(index, 1);
```

and try to splice a negative index, which goes backward from the end of the string, which would give unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Your hidden `hfCustomerID` field is always rendered to the browser as an empty field, because you haven't bound it to anything in your `Model`.

I assume this table is inside a form which is being posted to your controller? If so, then you could add a new field to your Model, and then use `@Html.HiddenFor` to render a hidden input field which is bound to that item in your model.

Alternatively, it looks like this field is entirely calculated based on the ticked checkboxes? In which case, update your view to set the value of the hidden field (this will duplicate some logic from your JavaScript though).

Comment: can you give some example?

Comment: @ShridharSalunkhe If you update the question to show the whole .cshtml view, and your controller code, I'll be able to show you more easily what I mean.

Comment: in this table,when checked box checked then checked box value is stored in hidden field using JavaScript. i Used mvcpaging nuget package for pagination.so when i checked value then it stored in hidden field when i go to next page hidden field is empty. i want to get previous page checked value and add new checked value in hidden field

Comment: I'm not familiar with the MvcPaging package, but it looks like it will re-load the whole view every time the user changes the page. This will throw away the hidden input value. So you will need to either find some other way of storing it (perhaps using localStorage in JavaScript?), or do the pagination a different way.